# Want to start a new activity but let the original activity finish first

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android activity we'll call *A* which has a button and another activity *B*. When the user clicks the button in Activity *A*, I'd like to finish *A* (let both `onStop` and `onDestroy` finish running) and then start up the instance of B. When I put a `finish()` and `startActivity()` call in the button click listener, the instance of *B* starts up before the old instance of *A* finishes. Can someone help me figure out a way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Any particular reason? Is there something specific you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's some cleanup code in onDestroy of A that is cleaning up things that are getting created in activity B.

Comment: @ajma: I've never tried this but it might be a fun experiment....create an instance member in `Activity A`. A `boolean`, for example, which is normally set to `false` and called `startActivityB`. Call `finish()` as you are now but not `startActivity(...)`. In `onDestroy()` do your cleanup and then check the `startActivityB` state - if it is `true` then call `startActivity()` from there. Interesting experiment - no idea if it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible and actually is against Android's activity lifecycle implementation.

**Correction**
It is possible with `android:noHistory="true"` tag in your manifest, but for what you are trying to do it seems wrong (read the EDIT)... Messing with the activity stack makes a non intuitive application!

Android OS doesn't let you control when activities will be removed from memory (or killed), and therefore all these fancy "Task killers" are so popular (DONT use them, they only make things worse).
When your activity's `onStop()` is being called, the activity stops completely, and it just hangs in your memory, but that's fine...

If you want to reset the state of `activity A`, or close the app when exiting `activity B`, just create a set of rules in both `onResume()` and `onStop()`, you can do everything you wish by creating a set of rules in those functions.

for example: have a boolean in `activity A` that turns `true` just before calling `activity B`,call finish() on your `activity A`'s if this boolean is `true`

I suggest that you take a look at [Android's Activity lifecycle diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), and make sure that everything you do follows the best practice.

**EDIT**

I saw your comment, it seems like you are trying to create things that are already in your memory, don't recreate them, it's a waste of CPU time, memory, and battery.
Instead, create a static class with a singleton that will hold all your shared data !

Comment: so there's no way for me to wait for activity A to finish? If I had something like the ability to wait for the parent activity to finish, then I could delay my code in B to wait for A to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for 
    onPause()

which is what gets called when the activity is sent to the background. You can do whatever cleanup you want in there. onStop should only be called when a user is exiting out of your program (or launching another one)

Comment: If the code calls `finish()` it WILL go through the complete destruction phase via `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`. The point of `onPause()` is not to do completed clean-up operations as everything would have to be re-created in `onResume(...)` which will lead to a lot of unnecessary processing. The point of the `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` stages are to allow graceful clean-up with `onDestroy()` being the last-chance.

Answer (score 0):

`onPause` is a better place to do this cleanup. See the [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) section of the [Activity doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

> When an activity's onPause() method is called, it should commit to the backing content provider or file any changes the user has made. **This ensures that those changes will be seen by any other activity that is about to run.** You will probably want to commit your data even more aggressively at key times during your activity's lifecycle: for example before starting a new activity, before finishing your own activity, when the user switches between input fields, etc.

While I'm not definite that your cleanup is for user changes, the bold sentence above implies that `onPause` will complete before the next `Activity` is created. Of course that probably implies that you'll have to move some setup to `onResume`...

Alternatively, you could move all your cleanup code to a method, let's just call it `cleanup` and then just call it before you start activity B. You'll have to put in appropriate guards for your `onDestroy` cleanup too of course.

Comment: But `onPause()` will be called when the user receives a phone call (for example) or if a popup dialog appears in front of Activity A. The point in the quote above that says "...commit your data even more aggresively..." indicates that `onPause()` is NOT normally the place for clean-up operations.

Comment: Yep, `onPause` can be called at other times as well which is why I mentioned that you would have to move some setup to `onResume`. I disagree however that your quote indicates `onPause` isn't normally the place for cleanup. Committing user data is different from cleanup. Even assuming the two are related enough to be roughly equated, this simply means that `onPause` is *one* of the places to do cleanup, though certainly not the only.

Comment: It depends on the context of 'clean-up'. To be honest, the OP's question is still pretty vague and without seeing at least some pseudo-code it's difficult to provide a good answer. Sure you mentioned moving some setup to `onResume(...)` but how much setup / teardown / clean-up do you want in an `Activity` bearing in mind the resume / pause / resume loop is the tightest in the `Activity` life-cycle and may be followed many times. Do long-term setup in `onCreate(...)`, short-term in `onResume(...)`, save state in `onPause()` and final teardown in `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

- override `finish()` method.
- implement `cleanUp()` method.
- create `boolean isClean=false` in the activity
- in `cleanUp()` write your clean up code.
- call `cleanUp()` in your `finish()`
- check for `isCleaned` in `finish()` or in `cleanUp()` if its true then ignore the clean
- now before you start `B` , call `cleanUp()` and set `isCleand=true`
- after you call `B` , call `finish()`

Answer (score -1):

1. Start activity A
2. from inside A startService(c) and finsh A
3. from inside the service , start Activity B